# how to save byte[] in DB through Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

ERROR: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

--> spring tool suite

--> oracle database 11g express edition

--> ojdbc6

--> hibernate tools

--> hibernate-release-4.3.9.Final   ,everything that was in folder "required"

```
antlr-2.7.7
dom4j-1.6.1
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final
hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final
jandex-1.1.0.Final
javassist-3.18.1-GA
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final
```

entity:

```
package firstPack.secondPack.testPack;

public class SaveMe {
    int id;
    byte[] bytedImg;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public byte[] getBytedImg() {
        return bytedImg;
    }
    public void setBytedImg(byte[] bytedImg) {
        this.bytedImg = bytedImg;
    }
}
```

SaveMe.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Apr 30, 2015 10:26:33 AM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="firstPack.secondPack.testPack.SaveMe" table="ASAVEME">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="bytedImg" type="binary" length="20000000">
            <column name="BYTEDIMG"></column>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">SYSTEM</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">SYSTEM</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="firstPack/secondPack/testPack/SaveMe.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

server side

```
    package firstPack.secondPack.testPack;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class HibClass {
    static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private static Configuration configuration;
    static{
        try {
            configuration=new Configuration().configure();
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory= configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System .err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + e);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
    public void saveIt(SaveMe saveMe) {
        System.out.println("Array length = "+saveMe.getBytedImg().length);
        try {
            Session sessin = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            sessin.beginTransaction();
            sessin.save(saveMe);
            sessin.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("It Have Been Commited");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Failed at the DataBase");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

to test it i wrote Applet, and run it locally, so it has access to server side

```
package firstPack.secondPack.testPack;

public class MyApplet extends JApplet{
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        populateGui();
    }
    JPanel mainPanel;
    JPanel imgPanel;
    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JButton button;
    Image img;
    byte[] bytedImg;
    int id=1;
    SaveMe saveMe;
    HibClass hibClass;
    private void populateGui() {
        hibClass=new HibClass();
        fetchImg();
        imgPanel=new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        imgPanel.setPreferredSize(
                new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null))
                );
        button=new JButton("Save");
        button.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        saveMe=new SaveMe();
                        saveMe.setBytedImg(bytedImg);
                        saveMe.setId(id);
                        hibClass.saveIt(saveMe);
                    }
                }
                );
        buttonPanel=new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(button);
        mainPanel=new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(imgPanel);
        mainPanel.add(button);
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);

    }
    private void fetchImg() {
        JFileChooser flCh = new JFileChooser("Choose Map Image");
        flCh.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "only image file", "jpeg", "jpg", "gif", "png"));
        flCh.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        flCh.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));

        int result = flCh.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                File file=flCh
                        .getSelectedFile();
                img=(Image) ImageIO.read(file);
                bytedImg=new byte[
                                           (int)file.length()
                                           ];
                FileImageInputStream inputStr=
                        new FileImageInputStream(file);
                inputStr.read(bytedImg);
                inputStr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error at opening Image File");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("File has not bean choosen");
        }
    }
}
```

as a result

```
apr 30, 2015 2:56:15 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
apr 30, 2015 2:56:15 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.9.Final}
apr 30, 2015 2:56:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
apr 30, 2015 2:56:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
apr 30, 2015 2:56:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
apr 30, 2015 2:56:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
apr 30, 2015 2:56:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: firstPack/secondPack/testPack/SaveMe.hbm.xml
apr 30, 2015 2:56:16 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
apr 30, 2015 2:56:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
apr 30, 2015 2:56:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe]
apr 30, 2015 2:56:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=SYSTEM, password=****}
apr 30, 2015 2:56:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
apr 30, 2015 2:56:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
apr 30, 2015 2:56:16 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
apr 30, 2015 2:56:16 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
apr 30, 2015 2:56:16 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
apr 30, 2015 2:56:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
apr 30, 2015 2:56:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
apr 30, 2015 2:56:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
apr 30, 2015 2:56:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: ASAVEME
apr 30, 2015 2:56:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: ASAVEME
apr 30, 2015 2:56:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: ASAVEME
apr 30, 2015 2:56:17 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Array length = 332200
Hibernate: insert into SYSTEM.ASAVEME (BYTEDIMG, ID) values (?, ?)
apr 30, 2015 2:56:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1461, SQLState: 72000
could not execute statement
Failed at the DataBase
apr 30, 2015 2:56:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

apr 30, 2015 2:56:31 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at firstPack.secondPack.testPack.HibClass.saveIt(HibClass.java:32)
    at firstPack.secondPack.testPack.MyApplet$2.actionPerformed(MyApplet.java:56)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 49 more
```

in Data Source Explorer, the table created has

```
BYTEDIMG[RAW(255)Nullable]
ID[NUMBER(10,0)PK]
```

so...

since length of

```
<property name="bytedImg" type="binary" length="20000000">
        <column name="BYTEDIMG"></column>
</property>
```

is around 20M, and

```
Array length = 332200
```

why there is

```
ERROR: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

why row "BYTEDIMG" is of type "RAW(255)", and not "BLOB"

Comment: Question is so lengthy..try to minimize it. try to shortly explain what error are you facing?

Comment: Long Oracle data type is text only and deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the problem

```
ERROR: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

arise from the fact that someone trying to save object that exceeds default "CHUNK" size, I'm not sure how much it is (4000 or 4500)

the solution is to increase default CHUNK size, but it should be done not in "property" but in "column" TAG

from

```
<property name="bytedImg" type="binary" length="20000000">
        <column name="BYTEDIMG"></column>
</property>
```

to

```
<property name="bytedImg"  type="binary" >
        <column name="BYTEDIMG" length="20000000"></column>
</property>
```

now it's around 20M